# Laravel spatie/laravel-permissions Naming Conventions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, naming-conventions, user-permissions, laravel-permission

Are there some naming guidelines I should be following when it comes to naming permissions? Right now, everything I find is just along the lines of "Add Foo","Edit Foo","Delete Foo","Add FooBar","Edit FooBar","Delete FooBar", and so forth and so forth.

Keeping in mind that there is no grouping (which is a real pity), and when you have a management screen for all said permissions - the above approach seems quite sloppy.

All your "adds" are together, "edits" are together, etc.
eg:

```
 - Add Foo
 - Add FooBar
 - Add FooBarBez
 - Edit Foo
 - Edit FooBar
 - Edit FooBarBez
 - Delete Foo
 - Delete FooBar
 - Delete FooBarBez
```

Right now I'm leaning towards something along the lines of what route names look like, for example:

```
 - foo.add
 - foo.edit
 - foo.delete
 - foobar.add
 - foobar.edit
 - foobar.delete
 - foobarbez.add
 - foobarbez.edit
 - foobarbez.delete
```

It's more organised in terms of keeping all the 'parent' permissions together (ie: all Foo's together, all FooBar's together, etc). Of course, if there are actual guidelines for this, please do let me know or if you have other valuable input / suggestions?

//Edit Update for Clarity

Specifically,

```
- __Are__ any naming conventions? 
- Are there any preferences in terms of use of singular/plural when it comes to parents (eg: "User Create", "Users Create")
- If parents and action should be separated with a space, a dot, something else? (eg: "users.create"; "users create"; "users->create")
- What about nested resources (Parent.Child)? eg: "users.banking_details.create"
- Captilisation? Lowercase? Camel Case?
```

As mentioned previously, leaning towards laravel named routes as the guideline so would be: plural, lowercase, separated by dots, including full path (parent+child relationship). Just because thats what I'm leaning towards, doesnt mean its right though, hence me asking for input from the community :)

Answer (score 5):

> Are any naming conventions?

Not that I know of. As you pointed out, the examples use "Create post" etc. which is a horrible way of handling it.

> Are there any preferences in terms of use of singular/plural when it comes to parents (eg: "User Create", "Users Create")

It really depends on your usage. Here's an example of using singular and plural for different instances.

A route which returns a single user could be protected by `user.read` and a route which returns multiple users could be protected by `users.read`. I believe the best way to do this is by using what makes sense to you and/or your team.

> If parents and action should be separated with a space, a dot, something else? (eg: "users.create"; "users create"; "users->create")

Dots are the preferred method, especially if you're going to be using wildcards.

> What about nested resources (Parent.Child)? eg: "users.banking_details.create"

Perfectly fine to use, however, be careful when it comes to wildcard permissions. A [wildcard](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/wildcard-permissions#using-wildcards) permission will give permission to use **ALL** child permissions.

If you were to give someone the permission `users` or `users.*` which are treated the same, they would be able to perform all permissions under this parent.

> Captilisation? Lowercase? Camel Case?

Pick a consistent style and stick to it.

I personally use the naming convention commonly used for web actions (CRUD).

```
task.create
task.read
task.update
task.delete
```

Comment: Good idea.  I have been thinking about this.  Also, what if a vendor product has similar permissions to a generic name like  "edit posts," for example?  I'm thinking of prefixing all app permissions with something.

Comment: If you have multiple vendors and there may be a clash with permission names, you could definitely prefix it with the vendors name.

Answer (score 4):

I would use [the same names that Laravel uses when authorizing resources](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d8433be23d5c5e5a2f1d2467add559ffbf099e7c/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/AuthorizesRequests.php#L105-L115):

- `view`
- `create`
- `update`
- `delete`

You can read more about this here: [**Gate and authorization improvements in Laravel**](https://josephsilber.com/posts/2016/08/03/authorization-improvements-in-laravel-5-3).

Comment: Yes, thanks - this is helpful; but doesn't give any feedback regarding the whole question - just some of it.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation they list a sample seeder, and give other examples.
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

```
'edit articles'
'delete articles'
'publish articles'
'unpublish articles'
```

I don't think it's a good convention, so I ended up with this in PostController:

```
function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
  $this->middleware(['permission:post create'], ['only' => ['create', 'store']]);
  $this->middleware(['permission:post edit'],   ['only' => ['edit', 'update']]);
  $this->middleware(['permission:post delete'], ['only' => ['delete']]);
}
```

I had to use $this each time, because it doesn't seem like you can chain middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using foo or something, simply use

- Create
- edit
- view
- update
- destroy
  It would help and make the steps easier when you started working for authentication.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the use of 'foo' / 'foobar' etc. Its just a placeholder/pseudo code. ie a real example would be users.create ; users.delete ; etc.